# kali linux виснет экран

Tags: kali-linux

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
после запуска kali linux просто виснет экран
помогите, как исправить
запускал через virtual box

Answer (score 0):

Для начала попробуй включить Virtualization Technologies в биосе. Затем попробуй поставить такие настройки...

Открываем настройки в Virtualbox:

Создаём и указываем верно систему гостевой (Debian и разрядность гостевой).

Система-процессор-ЦПУ-97-98% Галку поставить на "включить PAE/NX".

Система-материнская плата-основная память-1024 Мб.

Ставим галку на I/O APIC в дополнительных возможностях.

Стартуем систему,указав диск как динамический и путь к скачанному Iso-образу Kali.

И в настройках -дисплей-экран-видеопамять -128Мб поставить бегунок.

Comment: неа, все сделал не помогло

Comment: виснет на логотипе загрузки? сделай скриншоты на настройки ОС.